# I didn't go to sleep though I wanted to

Tags: infinitives

If I want to say

**I didn't go to sleep but I wanted to go**

can I say

**I didn't go to sleep but I wanted to (go)** ?

I heard we had to still write this **"to"** showing that **"wanted"** was followed by a verb, not some noun...

Comment: are you asking if you still need to 'to' if you drop the 'go'?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I meant

Comment: yes you do, but i don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need “to”.  You can say “but I wanted to” or “but I wanted to go to sleep” (wordy but grammatical).  You can’t say “but I wanted to go” or “but I wanted”.

Answer (score 1):

The following is syntactical:

> I wanted.

In its intransitive sense, it's similar to *I felt* or *I needed* or *I hurt*.

However, it's not very idiomatic. It's very likely that the following conversation would ensue:

> "I wanted."
>   "You wanted *what*?"

---

In the same sense, it's *possible* to say the following:

> ？ I didn't go to sleep but I wanted.

However, the same issue would occur. Anybody hearing or reading that would ask, "You wanted *what*?"

---

The problem is that this particular phrasing needs to be using a transitive form of *want* so that the object of the want is explicitly understood.

That's why, at least to be idiomatic, it needs to be one of these:

> ✔ I didn't go to sleep but I wanted *to <sup>[go to sleep]</sup>*.
>   ✔ I didn't go to sleep but *it's what* I wanted.
>   ✔ I didn't go to sleep *as* I wanted <sup>*[to do]*.</sup>

The words inside square brackets can be omitted, but they will be understood to be implied.

---

Either of the following would be fine:

> I didn't go, but I wanted to go.
>   I didn't go, but I wanted to <sup>[go].</sup>

In both of those cases, the parallel nature of the constructions work, and when *go* is omitted in the last part of the second sentence, we assume its presence.

However, this doesn't work:

> ？ I didn't go to sleep, but I wanted to go.

Although the syntax is fine, the meaning of the sentence would be interpreted in a way other than what's intended:

> I didn't go to sleep, but I wanted to *leave*.

This is because *to go*, on its own, means *to leave*. If we parse the sentence, it's much more common to interpret it in that sense than to assume that *to go* actually means *to go <sup>to sleep</sup>*.

Comment: You mean if we want to say "I didn 't go to sleep, but I wanted to (go)" we always have to omit the second "go" because it would be understood like "leave" while presence of "to" makes the syntax fine?

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko That's correct. For whatever reason, leaving in only the second *go* gives it a different idiomatic meaning (even if it's to sound strange) than you would expect from ellipsis.